# C# Get instance from a click event made by a contextmenu

Tags: c#

I've got the following code (simplified):

```
private ContextMenuStrip createContextMenuStrip(Card card)
{
    ContextMenuStrip cms = new ContextMenuStrip();
    cms.Items.Add("Send to the top of the deck", null, sendToDeck);
    return cms;
}

public void sendToDeck(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // **
}
```

The class `Card` has a member of the type `PictureBox`. On this `PictureBox`, the `ContextMenu` will be created. This works perfectly so far, BUT:

Here I want to access the instance the corresponding Card class which includes the clicked PictureBox's `ContextMenu`.

What possibilities do I have to achieve this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx) which can refer to your `card` variable (see "Variable Scope in Lambda Expressions") and pass it to your method:

```
private ContextMenuStrip createContextMenuStrip(Card card)
{
    ContextMenuStrip cms = new ContextMenuStrip();
    cms.Items.Add("Send to the top of the deck", 
                  null, 
                  (sender, e) => sendToDeck(sender, e, card));
    return cms;
}

public void sendToDeck(object sender, EventArgs e, Card card)
{
    // **
}
```

Assuming however that you don't care about feeding the `object sender` and `EventArgs e` in, it just becomes:

```
private ContextMenuStrip createContextMenuStrip(Card card)
{
    ContextMenuStrip cms = new ContextMenuStrip();
    cms.Items.Add("Send to the top of the deck", 
                  null, 
                  (sender, e) => sendToDeck(card));
    return cms;
}

public void sendToDeck(Card card)
{
    // **
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Control` have a property `Tag` of type `object` where you can store data linked to the control.
In your case you can strore the card:

```
private ContextMenuStrip createContextMenuStrip(Card card)
{
    ContextMenuStrip cms = new ContextMenuStrip();
    var item = cms.Items.Add("Send to the top of the deck", null, sendToDeck);
    item.Tag = card; // so you have the card in your contextmenu
    return cms;
}
```

Then you can recovery in the event

```
public void sendToDeck(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var card = (Card)((Control)sender).Tag;
}
```